# Where does MetaMask keep the API key of Infura?

Tags: metamask, infura, external-api

Since Infura always require an API key for its users, and Metamask by default uses Infura, it makes me wonder: where does MetaMask keep the API key **of Infura**?  Not a private of a wallet, but an API key.

Can it be seen and how?

I haven't found an answer anywhere.

P.S.

what's happen when the API quota of the key gets exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

The API key is buried inside the MetaMask binary.

It can be extracted using reverse engineering techniques.

Comment: That's a lie. Metamask is a browser extension, and as such it's written in JS. That is, there's nothing "binary" in there. Moreover, give me a proof of your claim.

Comment: I suggest you go and try to read MetaMask JavaScript source code. It is obfuscated to the point it is not readable.

Comment: Also why do you have so bad attitude. People here are trying to help you. Please do not be an asshole and you will get more useful feedback.

Comment: If the code is obfuscated, how do you know that the API key is inside it?

Comment: Because I have been working with MetaMask and Ethereum for 7 years.

Comment: Also, you're very rude. You won't get along with people.

Comment: Unlike you, I don't need to get along with people, because I know answers to all questions.

Comment: Give me a proof that an API key is inside Metamask. And you haven't answered my 2nd questiion.

Comment: There is no need for me to prove you anything. If you are too cheapskate to get your API key please go to learn reverse engineering.

Comment: I see that you're harsh. How can you show so much disrespect towards others?

Comment: If there's no need for your to give me a proof, your answer is of no value

Comment: I suggest you write an email to MetaMask support if you want to reverse engineer their product. Now be a good kid and go to learn some programming.

Comment: As people have seen already, you're unable stop to argue, nor stop to insult me.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa your answer is correct. Btw, one question.
In current metamask version, I can't find any request to infura in the network tab of browser developer tools. In the past, I was able to see, but not now. Do you know why?
I'm sure they still use infura key for mainnet

Comment: I am not helping anyone to misuse MetaMask API keys. That's would be sad. Instead, go here and find an Ethereum node provider for yourself: https://ethereumnodes.com/ - and don't use Infura, it is one of worst providers out there

Comment: Sorry, my intention is not getting api key or find a good node query api for my project. I'm studying metamask and want to know how it works under the hood.